# Set height and padding for ListView item that contains Label and Switch/Toggle Button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

We are using a **ListView** and every row of the list contains a **Label** and a **Switch**, there is some margin around the Switch, which wishes to remove.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Xaml**:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEnums}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

What can we do to remove/reduce the **spaces** between the list rows and how to set Height and Padding for Toggle button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Grid height:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEnums}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Height="your_height">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: We don't have Height in UWP Xamarin, we should use HeightRequest. Btw It worked for us. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Andrej: Thanks, Done.